# WebCrawling User-authenticated websites

Tags: c#, sockets, web-crawler

Is it possible to crawl user-authenticated websites using c#?

Comment: WHy do you want to use sockets? every thing you have to do to use sockets for HTTP requests have already been done for you. So what's the purpose of using sockets?

Comment: I already have a webcrawler using c# sockets. I tried .NET's HTTP and WebClient but they seem to use more CPU and memory and I can't use multithreading.

Comment: A properly written crawler implementation using `WebClient` wouldn't use more memory nor CPU (or at least no noticeable difference) and of course you could use multithreading with `WebClient`, it's just that you need multiple instances of it for each thread. `WebClient` also has asynchronous methods.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible assuming you have the credentials. Depending on the authentication mechanism used by the site different methods exist. [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) could be used to send HTTP requests to the remote sites.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible by using sockets?

Comment: Yes but that would be insane if the site uses HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

To crawl user-authenticated websites, your crawler should be able to handle cookies and POST-requests.

The question is: do you want your crawler to sign up, validate itself by email and then sign in to crawl all contents?

Comment: i already have the credentials, i think its using form authentication. Can i use c# sockets to do this? What commands should I use? thanks...:)

Comment: I suppose you could use **WebClient** or **HttpWebRequest**, as @Darin Dimitrov suggests.

Comment: Yes, sockets are a bad idea, lots of work for no reason (unless you have one of course?).  If you're also asking 'what commands should I use' then it sounds like you haven't read up on the HTTP protocol; in which case using the .NET web classes is an even better idea